# yii2 deny user login on backend

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I have yii2 advance template with RBAC migration applied. I was trying to learn RBAC and followed the [Docs 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html).

I have logged in using database, but the front-end and back-end both get logged in with any account. I have made 2 RBAC roles (admin, user), but can't understand or find how to

> restrict back-end to login non-admin user-role.

The following is the code for roles. and database entries:

```
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        // add "admin" role
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($admin);

        // add "user" role
        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $auth->add($user);

        $auth->assign($admin, 1);
    }
}
```

User Table:

```
admin   admin@gmail.com     20  10  1421197319  1421197319
user    user@gmail.com      10  10  1421198124  1421198124
```

Current rules:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
        'allow' => true,
    ],
    [
        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
    ],
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solved - Note: The solution is not exactly RBAC but ACF.**

After searching and consulting, I found the solution at [This yii2
viki.](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user)

I was unclear of RBAC behavior, in that I thought it won't let a role
perform specific task before some action(login, submit etc).

Actually, RBAC will let you do whatever you try, and afterwards checks
for permission and block if not permitted.

**Example**

> There is some yard sale in a house and you are free to roam
>   around it's front yard. The house gate/entrance doesn't have any guard
>   at front and its not locked. You try to sneak into the house and as
>   soon you get into the house there is some security guard inside who
>   abruptly stops you to identify yourself, he scan your information in
>   the house security system(permissions in DB) and doesn't find your
>   right to be in the house. He forces you out. This guard is RBAC
>
> I needed a guard at the front gate, who won't let anybody in unless
>   they are allowed to. And that would be ACF.
>
> So, now I needed a way to tell the back-end system that a specific
>   role cannot perform a specific action beforehand (i.e. deny non-admin
>   login at back-end), this is not possible with RBAC so, for that we
>   could use 'matchCallback' using ACF.

**Backend Rules:**

```
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    return Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin;
                }
            ],
         ]
```

The `matchCallback` on True allows the actions to be performed and on False denies the action. `isAdmin` is a getter function that needs to be defined in `User` model.

```
namespace /common/models/User;

const ROLE_ADMIN = 20;
public function getIsAdmin()
{
    return $this->role == self::ROLE_ADMIN;
}
```

I have posted the complete working code of model in [This yii2 viki's comments.](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user#c18825)

Answer (score 2):

You both first login user and then checking his role, there is no need for that.
Your LoginForm model has `getUser()` method, find it after calling `load()` and `validate()`, and check role with `authManager`. Smth like this:

```
    /** @var LoginForm $model */
    $model = Yii::createObject('loginForm');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $model->getUser();
        if (!empty($user) && Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess($user->getId(), 'admin')) {
            // Don't validate twice
            $model->login(false);
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->addError('email', 'This user is not authorized for administration');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('login.twig', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

You also don't want to `validate()` LoginForm twice, so add `$runValidation` param to the `login()` method.

```
public function login($runValidation = true)
{
    if ($runValidation) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add behavior to you controller, like this:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['create', 'delete', 'update'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['user'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

or this **EDIT:** (rule so that anyone is allowed to access login but only admin is allowed to be logged in and access index page):

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 reply. This does not work. There are already behaviors in controller of backend. how can i make a rule so that anyone is allowed to access login but only admin is allowed to be logged in and access index page. There are only 2 pages index and login in backend. If i do action=>[login, index, error] roles=>[admin]. It will not even view the login page, bcoz current user is guest. and according to the rule an admin role is required. i have tried it. and the problem is as i explained.

Comment: Ensure that you have RBAC tables in you DSN and your user "admin" have assigned role "admin". Example how to set access to actions is here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: I had a problem where I wanted to allow public access to index page in Yii2 backend and your code gave me that clue :) [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],                                                                                                                                    Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this functionality by changing backend login action. 
here is my code, i don't know, it is a perfect solution or not, but it is working for me.

```
public function actionLogin()
{    
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        //check user roles, is user is Admin? 
        if (\Yii::$app->user->can('Admin'))
        {
            // yes he is Admin, so redirect page 
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        else // if he is not an Admin then what :P
        {   // put him out :P Automatically logout. 
            Yii::$app->user->logout();
            // set error on login page. 
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'You are not authorized to login Admin\'s penal.<br /> Please use valid Username & Password.<br />Please contact Administrator for details.');
            //redirect again page to login form.
            return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
        }

    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works but there is some fundamental problem. U r 1st loging a user which is not supposed to be logged in the 1st place. U r doing extra work. I already new this workaround.  try my solution. Its better